# Difference between launchWhenStarted and repeatOnLifecycle(STARTED) in collecting flows

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

> As launchWhenStarted and repeatOnLifecycle(STARTED) provide completely different functionality (launchWhenStarted suspends the execution of the coroutine, and repeatOnLifecycle cancels and restarts a new coroutine), if the names of the new APIs were similar (for example, using launchWhenever for the restarting APIs), developers could’ve got confused and even use them interchangeably without noticing.

[source](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/repeatonlifecycle-api-design-story-8670d1a7d333)

What is a simpler explanation for when to use which?

Comment: `launchWhenStarted suspends the execution of the coroutine, and repeatOnLifecycle cancels and restarts a new coroutine` This is the difference. If you have a running coroutine launched with `lauchWhen...` and the lifecycle goes below that level, the coroutine will be suspended (but will still be alive, so depending what else it does, you may be wasting resources in things you don't need). The newer `repeatOn...` is "smarter" as it can cancel the coroutine and start a new one when needed. The easiest way to see this, is to try them yourself.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`launchWhenStarted` is just a one-time delay.

`repeatOnLifecycle` creates a suspending point that acts as a handler that runs provided block every time the lifecycle enters provided state and cancels it whenever it falls below it (so for `STARTED` it happens when it gets stopped).

**Update:**

Notice that `launchWhenStarted` API is now deprecated because it could cause work to hang for a very long time.

Currently for a one-shot one-time delay it's recommended to `lifecycleScope.launch()` a new job and use [`withStarted{ }`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/WithLifecycleStateKt#(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner).withStarted(kotlin.Function0)) method within it to cause a suspension until started state is reached.

Detailed explanation of deprecation and replacements is in this this [google tracker issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270049505).

Answer (score 6):

`repeatOnLifecycle` restarts its coroutine from scratch on each repeat, and cancels it each time lifecycle falls below the specified state. It’s a natural fit for collecting most flows, because it fully cancels the flow when it’s not needed, which saves resources related to the flow continuing to emit values.

`launchWhenX` doesn’t cancel the coroutine and restart it. It just postpones when it starts, and pauses execution while below the specified state. They plan to deprecate these functions but I suspect there will need to be some replacement if they do, for the case where you are calling some time consuming suspend function and then want to do something when it’s done, like starting a fragment transaction. Using `repeatOnLifecycle` for this would result in redoing the time consuming action.

Comment: "for the case where you are calling some time consuming suspend function and then want to do something when it’s done, like starting a fragment transaction."

would it be better to use SharedFlow in this situation?

Comment: @ghiath, possibly, but it would be rather opinionated of the Jetpack library to expect you to use Flows for everything.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for the answer. I was looking for replacement of launchWhenX when I read their document about removing the said api in the future. I guess launchWhenX is the only option for now.

Answer (score 3):

A cold flow backed by a `channel` or using operators with buffers such as `buffer`, `conflate`, `flowOn`, or `shareIn` **is not safe to collect** with some of the existing APIs such as `CoroutineScope.launch`, `Flow<T>.launchIn`, or `LifecycleCoroutineScope.launchWhenX`, unless you manually cancel the `Job` that started the coroutine when the activity goes to the background. These APIs will keep the underlying flow producer active while emitting items into the buffer in the background, and thus wasting resources.

To solve this issue with these APIs, you’d need to manually cancel collection when the view goes to the background. but it sounds to be a boilerplate code.

That's why Google recommended `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.XXX)` to make it simple and safe.

`repeatOnLifecycle` is a suspend function that takes a `Lifecycle.State` as a parameter which is used to **automatically create and launch a new coroutine** with the block passed to it when the lifecycle reaches that `state`, and **cancel the ongoing coroutine** that’s executing the block when the lifecycle falls below the state.

Learn more from [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda)

Comment: If my ViewModel has a `stateIn` or `shareIn`, then the coroutine is scoped to `viewModelScope`. When my Activity collects the ViewModel's `StateFlow`, the `repeatOnLifecycle` is scoped to `lifecycleScope`. So if I used `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` and I enter the STOP state, yes the Activity will stop collecting the Flow but no the underlying hot `StateFlow` won't stop from collecting whatever cold `Flow` it collects using `stateIn`.


Correct me if I'm wrong but that's what I'm thinking while reading this answer.